# "Allow notifications" element not appearing when automating with Appium, while everything works manually

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, robotframework, android-notifications

I'm working on a E2E test automation of a mobile app using Robot Framework and Appium. The first thing when starting the app, is to allow for the app to Send Notifications, allow Calls Permissions, allow it to View Contacts etc. The test script is supposed to handle these notifications. After each test the Teardown clears the data and cache, so app settings are reset.

With Android 12 there were no issues and the tests ran fine. However with Android 13 the permissions policy for notifications was changed, and a new prompt was introduced into the app for Android 13 devices. The Allow Notifications prompt is supposed to be the first to appear, when starting the app. After that comes Calls Permissions etc.

When testing manually, everything works fine. The notifications prompt appears as it should and can be interacted with.

However when running the test through automation, the prompt does not seem to appear (instead the first prompt is the Calls Permissions one, which should be the second). The notifications remain in a blocked state, which results in tests failing, when they are supposed to interact with these notifications from the swipe-down menu. Without a keyword to process the Allow Notifications prompt, the tests should fail right away, but they don't, which makes me suspect that it simply doesn't appear.

The question is why?

I have tried to manually enable to notifications mid test from the Android native settings, which result in the tests functioning as they should, with the test being able to interact with the notification. I have also tried to introduce pauses into execution by using Sleep at different stages.

Is there any reason for the notifications prompt to not appear when using automation, but to function normally when using the app manually?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by giving the command via ADB to grant the permission to send notifications:

OperatingSystem.Run    adb -s ${phone['udid']} shell pm grant  android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS